# How to redirect to random HTML pages without repetition?

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect users from the index page (page 1) to 30 different pages, where the pages are chosen randomly without repetition. So far I can manage to redirect to random pages, but I get repetitions. After all pages 2-31 are redirected randomly, I want the users to see the same page 32. How do I do that?

My code where I try to manipulate with the links looks like this:

```
  $myLinks = array("../page2.html", 
    "../page3.html",
    "../page4.html", "../page5.html");  //It goes on until  page 31

$randomRedirection = $myLinks[array_rand($myLinks)]; 
header("Location: $randomRedirection");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it in the session. Store the array of possibilities in the user's session, then get the index of the next page, delete that index from the possibilities array, and redirect.

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["possibilities"]))
{
    //New user
    $_SESSION["possibilities"] = ["/page1.html", "/page2.html", ...];
}
else if(count($_SESSION["possibilities"]) == 0)
{
    //User has viewed all pages
    header("Location: page32.html");
}

$index = rand(0, count($_SESSION["possibilities"])-1);
//Array splice removes the given elements from the array and returns them.
$page = array_splice($_SESSION["possibilities"], $index, 1);
header("Location:{$page[0]}");

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried using your code but I get an error at the very last line. I have a mini form with a submit button on every page which redirects me to other pages. I had my previous code here ``` if ($conn->query($sql)){ exactly here } so I tried using your code here as well. I also tried putting it at the very beginning, right after opening the php tag, but I still get an error at the same line. Where do you think I might have made a mistake?

Comment: Hey David! I figured it out what my problem was, and your code helped me a lot. Thank you vey much!